# jee 6 jaxrs get file not found

Tags: rest, jax-rs, websphere, java-ee-6

I have a utility project having the source and the application

```
package com.x.framework.api;

import java.security.Principal;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.csx.enterprise.webframework.security.LDAPUser;
import com.csx.enterprise.webframework.util.FrameworkThreadProperties;
import com.csx.enterprise.webframework.util.Log;
import com.csx.enterprise.webframework.util.WebFrameworkConstants;


@Stateless
@Path("/security")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class SecurityResource {

   @Resource
   SessionContext ctx;

   @GET
   @Path("me")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMe() {
     ...
  }
```

---

```
package com.x.framework.api;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxrsApplication extends Application{

}
```

I have a web project with web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.x.framework.api.JaxrsApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CSXSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But when I hit the URL https://localhost:9443/webframework/api/security/me, I keeps getting Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /api/security/me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you deploying this in WAS Liberty or traditional?  And what version? If Liberty, what features do you have enabled?

I was able to make this work using the code you posted in Liberty with the jaxrs-1.1 and webProfile-6.0 features enabled.  I had to comment out the CSX security filter in the web.xml and the imports, but otherwise it should be the same.  Perhaps the CSX filter is interfering?  If you comment it out too, can you get it to run?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I am using traditional. The coding posted above is fine. I found it's the Eclipse didn't get the update published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coding is fine. I had to go to the installedApp directory and extracted the ear file and found the files were not updated accordingly by the Eclipse. So it's not a coding issue, but more of a publishing issue.